# Can a TrueCrypt container file be mounted from an external hard drive?

Tags: external-hard-drive, mount, truecrypt, container

I created a 200GB TrueCrypt container, and thinking that you should be able to mount it from anywhere, I transfered it to my external hard drive. Then I tried to mount it, but TrueCrypt won't even display my external hard drive in the folder list. However I did notice a "select device" button. That to me seems like TrueCrypt wants to treat the whole hard drive as a container. Am I correct in saying that?

If so, then I have to move all the other files I have backed up in there to some other storage device(s). This is getting to be ridiculous. I love TrueCrypt, but it is starting to get annoying and hard to work with.

Comment: what OS are you on, and can you see and open the external drive in your file manager?

Comment: I am using Linux Fedora Gnome

Comment: is your external drive mounted at the time you attempt to mount your volume with truecrypt, and does your user have access to the location its mounted to?

Comment: Yes, it was mounted and I transfered the container file, which took me 1 hour and 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can mount truecrypt volumes and devices from external media, or even over remote file share in linux or windows.

the "Select Device" options are for encrypted partitions, not file volumes, as you have surmised.

Make sure you can view your volume file in your hosts file manager. if not the issue is your OS not the volume. you may need to touch the drive before it will appear to truecrypt.

are you able to mount the volume from the command line? since you are on fedora, you have [realcrypt](http://rpmfusion.org/Package/realcrypt). Create a folder in your home to mount the truecrypt volume in, and run

```
realcrypt PathToVolume PathToMountVolume
```

Comment: Frank, Truecrypt is working fine as long as you have the container file in the system, but I want to be able to mount the container file from external device.

Comment: yes I know. have you tried mounting via the command line while its on the external disk?

Comment: I have never mounted it via command line. I always used the GUI to create and mount container file, I although I did have to use command line to change the owner of my container file recently.

Comment: If this can't be done, then one will have to transfer the container file into the system. Then, load it with the files you want to "truecrypt" and once again transfer it back into the external hardrive.

Comment: please try it from the command line. that will tell you if you have a fedora/gnome issue, or a truecrypt issue, and hopefully give you hints about what to fix. I understand you usually use the gui and thats fine, but I am asking you to try the cli once and let us know if it worked.

Comment: okay. I will try it sometime today and back to you then. Thank you

Comment: Frank, I am at home and tried the command line. The system is saying that the command "trycrypt" is not found. I even logged in as a root user. Still, it is saying that it can't find the command. Truecrypt is installed on my system.

Comment: Frank, I tested and found some real information. Apparently, the command is not "truecrypt" but "realcrypt." However, it still doesn't work. This is the command I used "su realcrypt -v /dev/sdb1/DelphiSoftware." Then, it asked me to enter the container password. I thought I was out of the woods and I can say bye to Frank. LOL. Right after I entered the password, it came back and said, "this is not a directory." That's it. It quits after that.

Comment: interesting. anyway, I updated the link with the cli help to reflect realcrypt, and updated the command above. give it a try.

Comment: Frank, followed what you told me and I am still not able to mount the container which is in my USB hardrive on my fedora linux system. "sudo realcrypt /dev/sdb1/DelphiSoftware /home/thaya/tmpfile" is the cli command i used. Then, it asks me to enter password for /dev/sdb1/DelphiSoftware. Once I do that, it comes back and says, "No such file or directory." What do you think?

Comment: Frank, Just to be sure I looked into the container's properties and found the actual path which is "/run/media/thaya/Seagate Backup Plus Drive." When I tried to use this path in the cli command, system doesn't like the fact that there are spaces in the USB hardrive's name. It gives me "Unexpected error: Plus" and it hangs up on it. What should I do? what do I have to replace the spaces with?